# How to represent the Java "this" keyword in a constructor using UML

Tags: java, dependencies, uml, aggregation, composition

Say we have:

```
class A {
    A(B theB){
    }
}
```

and

```
class B {
    B() {
        A theA = new A(this);
    }
}
```

How should the relationship between A and B be represented using UML?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to establish a HAS A relationship, but neither class keeps a reference to an instance of the other. Could you provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing else but a cross-over dependency.

[image]

If you were to hold a property of one class in the other you would show that as association. But in this case it's just a dependency.

Comment: So the different type of constructors makes no difference for the UML representation?

Comment: No. Just the signature looks different (see the operations compartment)